# For an algebra $A$, show that the bimodule $A \otimes_{A \otimes A^{\text{op}}} A \cong \frac{A}{[A,A]}$.

Tags: algebras, topological-quantum-field-theory, bimodules

If A is an associative k-algebra, and $A^{\text{op}}$ represents the opposite k-algebra (i.e. $a*_{A^{\text{op}}} b := b\cdot a)$.

In the following we consider ${\cal A_1}=A$ as a right $A\otimes A^{op}$ bimodule and ${\cal A_2}=A$ as a left $A\otimes A^{op}$ bimodule. I want to prove the following isomorphism of $k-k$ bimodules (aka vector spaces): $$\large {\cal A_1} \otimes_{A \otimes A^{\text{op}}} {\cal A_2} \cong A/[A,A].$$

---

**Reference and context**: Page 17 of [this](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~djordan/lecture_notes_tft_seminar.pdf) article. I am reading articles on TQFT with the aim of understanding extended TQFTs. I hope I have presented the question faithfully from the linked article.

**My thoughts**: I am generally not comfortable with $A^{op}$ stuff. I know that a left $A \otimes A^{op}$ module is $A-A$ bimodule. And similarly right $A \otimes A^{\text{op}}$ module is a left $(A \otimes A^{op})^{op} = A^{\text{op}} \otimes A$ module.

The members of the bimodule ${\cal A_1} \otimes_{A \otimes A^{\text{op}}} {\cal A_2} =: \mathfrak{A}$ are generated by elements of the form $\alpha \otimes \beta$ with the condition $$\alpha \otimes (a\cdot \beta \cdot b) = (b \cdot \alpha \cdot a) \otimes \beta$$ for all $a,b,\alpha, \beta \in A$.

I see that the constraints force $$a \otimes b = 11a \otimes b = 1 \otimes ab1 = 1 \otimes 1ab = b \otimes a.$$

In order to prove the isomorphism I could think of two maps:

1) Consider the map $A \to \mathfrak{A}$ given by:

$$a \mapsto a \otimes 1.$$

2) Consider another map $\mathfrak{A} \to A/[A,A]$ given by:

$$a \otimes b \mapsto [ab].$$
Here $[x]$ represents the coset of an element $x (\in A)$ in the quotient.

I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea; to prove that $A/[A,A]$ and $\mathfrak{A}$ are isomorphic, it suffices to define homomorphisms $f : A/[A,A]\to\mathfrak{A}$ and $g : \mathfrak{A}\to A/[A,A]$ such that $gf = \operatorname{id}_{A/[A,A]}$ and $fg = \operatorname{id}_{\mathfrak{A}}.$

To get the map $f : A/[A,A]\to\mathfrak{A},$ it suffices to check that $\tilde{f}$ factors through the canonical projection $\pi : A\to A/[A,A].$ To do this, we may show that $\tilde{f}$ vanishes on generators of $[A,A].$ To that end, let $a,b\in A.$ Then
\begin{align*}
\tilde{f}(ab - ba)&= (ab - ba)\otimes 1\\
&= (ab)\otimes 1 - (ba)\otimes 1\\
&= (ab\cdot 1)\otimes 1 - (ba\cdot 1)\otimes 1\\
&= b\otimes (1\cdot 1\cdot a) - a\otimes (1\cdot 1\cdot b)\\
&= b\otimes a - a\otimes b\\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
so that $\tilde{f} : A\to\mathfrak{A}$ indeed factors as $A\xrightarrow{\pi} A/[A,A]\xrightarrow{f}\mathfrak{A}.$

The induced map $f : A/[A,A]\to\mathfrak{A}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f : A/[A,A]&\to\mathfrak{A}\\
[a]&\mapsto a\otimes 1,
\end{align*}
so we readily check that the composition $A/[A,A]\xrightarrow{f}\mathfrak{A}\xrightarrow{g} A/[A,A]$ is the identity, where $g$ is the map you defined in the question.

It remains to be shown that the composition $\mathfrak{A}\xrightarrow{g} A/[A,A]\xrightarrow{f}\mathfrak{A}$ is also the identity. It suffices to show that this holds for simple tensors. This composition is given on simple tensors by
\begin{align*}
fg(a\otimes b) &= f([ab])\\
&= ab\otimes 1\\
&= b\otimes a\\
&= a\otimes b,
\end{align*}
so that $fg = \operatorname{id}_{\mathfrak{A}},$ as desired. Thus, $\mathfrak{A}\cong A/[A,A].$

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.